# How to focus a main input when focus is lost from other inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a website where there's an input i need the focus on for the full time, due it's a barcode-reader. But there's also other inputs in the site that the user must be able to fill him self so I can't constantly focus the barcode-input.

I have been trying to make it works with an interval that auto-focus the barcode-input each 1.5s, stoping the interval when an input is focused and starting it again when the user focusOut some input. But it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(fucntion(){
        $('#barcode_input').focus();
    });

    $(":input").focusin(function(){
        if(barCodeFocusInterval) {clearInterval(barCodeFocusInterval);}
    });

    $(":input").focusout(function(){
        barCodeFocusInterval = setInterval(function(){
            $('#barcode_input').focus();
        }, 1500);
    });
</script>
```

I think it doesn't work because when the focusin is triggered, what should stop the interval, it already sent the order to focus the barcode_input so i can't focus any other input for more than 1.5s.

I don't really need to make it works with an interval but I've already tried too many things. Hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: Why not just wait for them to submit whatever other data they're entering, and then re-focus the main `input`? I wouldn't think an interval would be relevant based on your description.

Comment: I know the interval is not necesary but it was one thing i tried and i though it would help to understand the problem.
I can't wait for the submit, first of all because there are sooo many forms i can't edit one by one to focus the barcode_input after the submit, and second because some of this forms works with Knockout so the form is not even submited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood correctly - how about `setTimeout()`.

```
$(function() {
    var is_focused = false;

    function focus_to_barcode() {
        if (!is_focused) {
            $('#barcode_input').focus();
        }
    }   

    $(":input").focusin(function () {
        is_focused = true;
    });

    $(":input").focusout(function () {
        is_focused = false;
        setTimeout(focus_to_barcode, 1500);
    });
});
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cfeLtLzz/2/), pls

Comment: your example doesnt work, it shifts the focus back to the main element even when the user is trying to enter info in the other elements

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault for using the interval example. But this isn't the functionality i'm expecting due I'm not able to use the other inputs correctly. The main input should only be focused when the focus is lost from an input and the new focused element is not an input.

Comment: Your example clearly works as I expected so I set your awnser as correct but it doesn't work in my site. Some inputs from JQuery plugins like Knockout and DataTables still works wrong and lose the focus after 1.5s.

Comment: @Grirg that likely is because those plug-ins hide your original html (including the inputs) and replaces them with editable spans and divs that are styled all fancy and such.

Answer (score 0):

The below will:

- focus to the main div on load
- only allow the user to focus on other elements if they have the "allowed" class
- re-focus to the main div once a user clicks away from an element with the "allowed" class

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#barcode_input').focus();


   var elements = $( "body" ).find( "*" );

   $(elements).each(function(i, elm){
                 
     $(elm).blur(function(){
        if(this.id != 'barcode_input'){
             $('#barcode_input').focus();
         }
      });
      $(elm).focus(function(){
         if(this.id != 'barcode_input'&&!$(this).hasClass('allowed')){
             $('#barcode_input').focus();
         }
      });
  
                 
   });
  
});
```

```css
#someDiv{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   margin-top:30px;
   background-color:#cccccc;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="barcode_input"/>
<input type="text" class="allowed" id="barcode_input2"/>
<input type="text" class="allowed" id="barcode_input3"/>

<input type="text" id="someOtherInput" value="input that is not allowed" size="44"/><br>
<div id="someDiv" contentEditable="true">div that is not allowed<div>
```